# JQuery - Show/hide 2 divs with 1 button and change value of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I've trying to make it so when I click a button it will hide one div and show another but at the same time change the value of the button to reflect the different content of the divs.

I've been able to create the two functions but when I put them together it seems to break.

Here's the show/hide function

**Javascript :**

```
function change() {
     if (document.getElementById('tabs')) {
        if (document.getElementById('tabs').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('tabs').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('parkList').style.display = 'none';}
        else {
        document.getElementById('tabs').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('parkList').style.display = 'block';}
       }
     }
```

And here's the value change function

**Javascript:**

```
function change( el ) {
  if ( el.value === "div1" )
      el.value = "div2";
  else
      el.value = "div1";
 }
```

And here's the HTML for both

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">Div 1</div>
<div id="parkList">Div 2</div>

<input type="submit" value="div1" onclick="return change(this);"/>
```

I'm a bit of a novice so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `JQuery` [toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to switch the display property of matched element.

- By default `parkList` div is hidden.
- Add click listener on `submit` button.
- Toggle the display property of both the divs on click of submit button
- Set the value of submit button by visible div's content.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">Div 1</div>
<div id="parkList" style="display:none">Div 2</div>

<input type="submit" value="Div 1"/>

<script>
  
  var submit = $('input[type="submit"]');
  var tabs = $('#tabs');
  var parkList = $('#parkList');
  
  submit.click(function(e){
     tabs.toggle();
     parkList.toggle();
    
     if(tabs.css('display') == 'none'){
       submit.val(parkList.text());
     }else{
       submit.val(tabs.text());
     }
  });
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a way that instead of using parkList.text and tabs.text to determine the change of the value, you can add the new values directly into the jQuery as I need the div content to be different to the value name if that makes sense?

Comment: Never mind I managed to figure it out. It's as simple as changing it to submit.val("View full park list"); instead of submit.val(parkList.text());.

Comment: @Braj how to save this toogle switch status into database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that 2 functions have the same name.

When you call `change()` to display block/none elements the most probably is to happen that you overrides with  `change(element)`

Change the second function name to `changeValue(el)` for example and it works

```
function changeValue( el ) {
  if ( el.value === "div1" )
     el.value = "div2";
  else
     el.value = "div1";
}

<input type="submit" value="div1" onclick="return changeValue(this);"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I change the second function name to changeValue(el) as you have done then the button will no longer active the first function. Is there anyway of having the two function attached to the one button?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 functions with the same name.
 `function change()`
Try renaming one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this, See below code for show/hide divs on button click:
No need to write two functions. Just call below function on button click.

```
function changeValue(){
   if($(this).text() === 'div1'){
      $(this).text('div2');
      $('div2').hide();
      $('div1').show();
   }else{
      $(this).text('div1');
      $('div1').hide();
      $('div2').show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't get this right, where are you calling show/hide function change() ?

Naming the button is working.. you need to assign an event listener to style or call the function, use jquery as below:

```
$('#tabs').show();
$('#parkList').hide();
```

And you need to change the method name of one of the two functions 'change'.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can make display none for second div

```
<input type="submit" value="tabs" onclick="return change(this);"/>

function change( el ) {
  if ( el.value === "tabs" )
  {
      el.value = "parkList";
      document.getElementById('tabs').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('parkList').style.display = 'block';}
  }
  else
  {
      el.value = "tabs";
      document.getElementById('tabs').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('parkList').style.display = 'none';} 
  }
 }
```